# msgraph-sdk-go example code for getting user's drive fails

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-api

The example code for the [msgraph-sdk-go](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go) to get a user's drive fails with a 401 error below.  It expects the request body to contain a client_secret, although there is no place in the example code to create a request body.

The example code does successfully authenticate to my registered application via a web browser.

What is required to use the msgraph-sdk-go?

Here's the code that fails:

```
result, err := client.Me().Drive().Get(context.Background(), nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error getting the drive: %v\n", err)
    printOdataError(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Found Drive : %v\n", *result.GetId())
```

Here's the error:

```
Error getting the drive: DeviceCodeCredential authentication failed
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/efa4b4f3-5e38-4866-9206-79c604d86e7c/oauth2/v2.0/token
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE 401 Unauthorized
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.\r\nTrace ID: b6f28bb4-6bed-4dfe-a275-c0343fb91e01\r\nCorrelation ID: c06d2257-b3ab-4df3-ba58-ab271cf97508\r\nTimestamp: 2023-02-14 14:18:22Z",
  "error_codes": [
    7000218
  ],
  "timestamp": "2023-02-14 14:18:22Z",
  "trace_id": "b6f28bb4-6bed-4dfe-a275-c0343fb91e01",
  "correlation_id": "c06d2257-b3ab-4df3-ba58-ab271cf97508",
  "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000218"
}
```

Edit:  Adding more detail for the answer from baywet

I have the client and device code credentials created as baywet shows but I added the TennantID field.

In point 5 I selected mobile/desktop application but with redirect URI of `http://localhost`.  I have different options for Redirect URIs than he has.

[image: Redirect URIs]

Point 6 was the key to getting it to work.  Once I selected `Yes` for `Enable the following mobile and desktop flows` my application worked.

[image: Allow public client flows]

I also had these API permissions.

[image: API permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you setup your client using the device code credentials given the error message you're getting with code similar to this

```
cred, err := azidentity.NewDeviceCodeCredential(&azidentity.DeviceCodeCredentialOptions{
    ClientID: "CLIENT_ID",
    UserPrompt: func(ctx context.Context, message azidentity.DeviceCodeMessage) error {
        fmt.Println(message.Message)
        return nil
    },
})

client := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClientWithCredentials(cred, []string{"User.Read"})
```

The registered application needs to be configured properly to allow for the device close flow.
For that:

1. Go to [the azure portal](https://add.portal.azure.com)
2. Navigate to the application registrations (Azure Active Directory, then Application registrations).
3. Find your application registration in the list.
4. Click on the authentication tab
5. Make sure the mobile and desktop applications platform is select with the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient` URL checked.
6. Make sur "Enable the following mobile and desktop flows" is set to "yes".
7. Click "save".

A couple of screenshots to guide you through.

[image: authentication platforms]
[image: device code flow]

Comment: I edited my question to show more details.  I show different Redirect URIs than you show and used `http://localhost`.  I also added `User.ReadAll` to API permissions.  Your steps work even though we have these differences.